# Vue, checking pre rendered checkboxes in modal from axios result

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

The code I have right now, in laravel, renders a table with links and each links opens a modal with info from that corresponding clicked row. At the time this modal opens, I also make an axios call in Vue that gets a result from an endpoint and returns it. ALl of this works. My only issue now is taking the result from the axios call and match it up to the checkbox names and check the correct ones.

In this case my result from axios is

```
0: {
    result_type: "mix"
}
1: {
    result_type: "internal"
}
```

So I would want to check the mix and internal checkboxes when this result comes in, but obviously I want this to occur whether there are no results or 3

How can I take this axios result and make sure it checks these boxes properly (if matched) when they are already technically rendered on page load?

```
    @foreach($getResults as $k => $result)
    <tr class="" id="">
        <td>
        <a id="show-modal" @click="showModal = {{$k}}; getDetails('{{$result->group_marketing_copyt_id}}');">{{$result->number}}</a>
        <modal v-if="showModal==={{$k}}" @close="showModal = false">
        <h2 slot="header">{{$result->number}}- {{$result->name}}</h3>
        <div slot="context" >

            <input type="checkbox" name='direct' data-md-icheck  />
            <input type="checkbox" name='internal' data-md-icheck  />
            <input type="checkbox" name='mix' data-md-icheck  />
        </div>

        <div slot="body">
        <textarea style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">{{utf8_encode($result->text)}}</textarea>
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach


    ...


    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
            data: { 
                showModal: false
            },
            methods: {
                getDetails: function(rID){
                    console.log(rID);
                    console.log('nice');

                    let data = {rID:rID};
                    axios.post('/details', data)
                    .then((response) => {

                        console.log(response.data);

                        //Here I want to take my results and push them into corresponding checkboxes

                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                    .finally(function () {
                        console.log('done');
                    });


    ...
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't slap ID's on your fields and target them with plain old JS?  ```document.getElementBy('somefield').value = response.data.something```

Comment: Not much of a laravel guy but I'd personally link up the checkboxes keys to data. It just makes things easier and you can easily update the checkbox values/do comparisons

Comment: so set the names of the checkbox as data elements in vue? @SujilMaharjan

Comment: @FAKETAXI I really wanted to try to keep this whole page in Vue if possible since we're already using it everywhere else. But also, each row has it's own modal so I can't use IDs on the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work...

```
   @foreach($getResults as $k => $result)
      <tr class="" id="">
        <td>
        <a id="show-modal" @click="showModal = {{$k}}; getDetails('{{$result->group_marketing_copyt_id}}');">{{$result->number}}</a>
        <modal v-if="showModal==={{$k}}" @close="showModal = false">
        <h2 slot="header">{{$result->number}}- {{$result->name}}</h3>
        <div slot="context" >

            <input :checked="direct" type="checkbox" name='direct' data-md-icheck  />
            <input :checked="internal" type="checkbox" name='internal' 
            data-md-icheck  />
            <input :checked="mix" type="checkbox" name='mix' data-md-icheck  />
        </div>

        <div slot="body">
        <textarea style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;">{{utf8_encode($result->text)}}</textarea>
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach


     new Vue({
            el:'#app',
                data: { 
                    showModal: false,
                    mix: false,
                    internal: false
                },
                methods: {
                    getDetails: function(rID){
                        console.log(rID);
                        console.log('nice');

                        let data = {rID:rID};
                        axios.post('/details', data)
                        .then((response) => {

                           response.data.forEach(element => {
                            if(element.result_type === "mix" ) {
                               this.mix = true;
                            } else if (element.result_type === "internal"){
                               this.internal = true;
                            }
                           });

                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                        .finally(function () {
                            console.log('done');
                        });
```